# Need help reading .cfg file

Tags: python, parsing, config, configparser

I am supposed to import configuration values contained in a `.cfg` file written as follows into my dictionary.

```
Category1 {
    Subcategory1 {
        Data1 = 120        # range [0:255]
        Data2 = "R_TRUE"   # Values "R_TRUE" "R_FALSE"
    }
    Subcategory2 {
        Data3 = 0
    }
}
```

When using `ConfigParser`, console tells me my file is lacking headers which I supposed are written like `[header]`.

This is my first time reading `.cfg` files and any example I found on internet was written like:

```
[Category1]
A = 0
B = 10
C = "R_TRUE"
```

So I was wondering:

1. If this`.cfg` file I have is really wrong or is it accepted syntax.
2. If you know what syntax the person who made it used so I may check its doc. Maybe he made it to be read by another language than Python?
3. Well if possible you can give me an example of parser for this!

Comment: This looks like a weird version of [`HOCON`](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md). You can try to search the interwebs for various config formats and if you're lucky you'll identify it and find a Python module that parses it, and if you're not you'll have to write the parser yourself.

Comment: @zwer It does indeed ressemble to json. I've been searching for a syntax that doesnt exist for too long so I am going to make my own parser for python i guess! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can build a parser for this using a few regex expressions. Here's an example.

```
cfg = '''\
Category1 {
    Subcategory1 {
        Data1 = 120        # range [0:255]
        Data2 = "R_TRUE"   # Values "R_TRUE" "R_FALSE"
    }
    Subcategory2 {
        Data3 = 0
    }
}'''

import re
category_match = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*{')
value_match = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*([0-9]+|"[^"]*")')
close_match = re.compile(r'}')

for line in cfg.split('\n'):
    m = category_match.search(line)
    if m:
        print ('1: ', m.groups()[0])
    m = value_match.search(line)
    if m:
        print ('2: ', m.groups()[:])
    m = close_match.search(line)
    if m:
        print ('3: close found')
```

The output is this.

```
1:  Category1
1:  Subcategory1
2:  ('Data1', '120')
2:  ('Data2', '"R_TRUE"')
3: close found
1:  Subcategory2
2:  ('Data3', '0')
3: close found
3: close found
```

In each output line, the number is the regex that matched the input line.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax seems to have been customized from HOCON (json). My best solution right now is making my own parser to adapt it to the syntax i want it to have.

I don't know how to close this subject but if someone has a real answer for anyone who gets the same kind of problem as i do, feel free to share it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) you may be able to save a lot of time by using the python [EBNFparser](http://ebnfparser.readthedocs.io/en/boating-new/quickstart.html#installing) package. [Docs](http://ebnfparser.readthedocs.io/en/boating-new/parsing.html)

Basically you give it the EBNF definition of a language and it creates a parser for you *(at least in theory)*.